# How to append a parameter to current page using CHtml::link?

Tags: yii

Using Yii, and trying to append a Lang=xx to the end of the current page url and present it on the page.

I put the below code in the protected/views/layout/main.php

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('English', array('','lang'=>'en'), array('class'=>'en')) ?>
<?php echo CHtml::link('中文', array('','lang'=>'tw'), array('class'=>'tw')) ?>
<?php echo CHtml::link('日本語', array('','lang'=>'jp'), array('class'=>'jp')) ?>
```

With standard pages like "/site/index", or controller action pages like "/site/contact", they work fine. But with the standard static pages like "site/page?view=about", it's not working. The url expected should be something like "site/page?view=about&lang=tw", but instead, it gives me "site/page?lang=tw".

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you just trying to provide a way for the user to set the `CLocale` of the Yii application? Or does each Controller look for the $_GET['lang'] parameter?

Comment: What I was trying to do is to provide a universal language switcher for the site. It turned out that  static pages work differently. I did mange to solve it, but it's a bit too long to repeat here. Please refer to the link if anyone is interested: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3148-extension-langhandler/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it with langhandeler extension and url rules and map [site]/[path]?lang=[language code] to [site]/[language code]/[path]

And then I coded the links like below:

```
        <?php 
        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path_a = explode("/",$request);
        $haveLang = isSet($_GET["lang"]);
        $uri = ($haveLang?
                substr($request, strlen($path_a[1])+1) //strip language prefix and the slash
                :$request);                               //don't process if the page is in default language
        echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name), CHtml::normalizeUrl(($haveLang?'/'.$_GET["lang"].'/':'/')), array('id'=>'logo')); 
        ?>
          <div id="lang_switch">                  
            <?php
            echo CHtml::link('English', CHtml::normalizeUrl($uri), array('class'=>'en')); //no need to add default language prefix
            echo CHtml::link('‰∏≠Êñá', CHtml::normalizeUrl('/tw'.$uri), array('class'=>'tw'));
            echo CHtml::link('Êó•Êú¨Ë™û', CHtml::normalizeUrl('/jp'.$uri), array('class'=>'jp'));
            ?>
          </div>
```

that pretty much solved my problem. I hope this could help out someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can give chtml link like this

```
$language = 'en';
CHtml::link("English", array('site/about/lang/' . $language));
```

*site/about/lang/en = controller/action/lang/en*

i hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you for the comment. However, I was looking for something a bit more dynamic. I needed links that would refer back to itself and add the language code to switch language.